# PHP. Удалить id из двух таблиц за один запрос?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Как удалить две записи (`id`) за один запрос? Пример:

`'DELETE /.../ user1.id = 3, user2.id = 1'`

Надо `JOIN`-ы использовать? Я только знаю как работать с

`SELECT /.../ JOIN /.../` , чуть-чуть.

---

```
$delete_id_from_db1 = 'DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ' . $delete_id_value;
$delete_id_from_db2 = 'DELETE FROM phones_users WHERE id = ' . $delete_id_value;
$result_delete1 = mysqli_query($con, $delete_id_from_db1);
$result_delete2 = mysqli_query($con, $delete_id_from_db2);
```

Comment: Кажется мне, что Вам нужно использовать внешние ключи с каскадным удалением

Comment: Поля не удаляют. Удаляют записи.

Comment: может из двух таблиц, а не баз данных?

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE users, phones_users 
FROM users u 
JOIN users_phones up ON u.id=up.user_id 
WHERE u.id=$id
```

При условии что во второй таблице есть поле `user_id`.

Когда хотите удалить что-то с `JOIN` сначала проверьте с помощью `SELECT`

Comment: При отсутствии записи в users из таблицы users_phones ничего удалено не будет.

Comment: Запрос понял, но что значит `u`  `up` ?

Comment: Алиасы таблиц. Чтобы не писать в ON и WHERE имена таблиц целиком